# How to determine if Firefox is currently running in headless mode at runtime?

Tags: selenium, firefox

I need to know whether or not the current browser under test is [firefox running in headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode). How can I find this information at runtime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find this information in the `Capabilities` of the firefox session under test.

```
console.log((await driver.getCapabilities()).get("moz:headless"));
```

This will return a boolean representing whether or not the firefox instance was launched using the `-headless` option [when the binary object was set up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode#Automated_testing_with_headless_mode).

Answer (score 0):

For those using Selenium with Python, the following approach worked for me (Firefox 106):

```py
if driver.caps.get("moz:headless", False):
    pass # running headless
```